# Mongoosejs text index an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-indexing

currently im having a problem regarding referencing text index in object
here's the code

Schema

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    fullname: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
  supplier: Boolean,
  supplierdetails: {
    name: String,
    businesstype: String,
    location: String,
    products: String,
    revenue: String,
    employees: String,
    yearsestablished: String
  }
});
UserSchema.index({supplierdetails: 'text'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

API

```
router.post('/findsupplier', function(req, res){
    User.find({supplier: true, $text: {$search: req.body.supplyData}}, {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
    .sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
    .exec(function(err, supplyResult){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else
            res.json(supplyResult);
    });
});
```

As you can see here "supplierdetails" is an object on my schema, and i tell mongoosejs to text index it, because i want to do a text index search on the whole supplierdetails object which contains name, businesstype, products, location and etc.., i saw on my mongo shell the created index
[image]

But it's still not working
This is my data on database

[image]

I searched "dog" or "shiba" but still returning me no results.

My other functionality which uses text index is perfectly working, the only difference is, the one that i've text index isn't an object, it's just a String property and it perfectly works

Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Is _shiba_ sent in the `req.body.supplyData` ?

Comment: yes. i tried to console.log it, and it shows up

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/), you can only create a text index on a String or Array of Strings, not an object (that happens to contain Strings).